# Changing output file name in a batch file

Tags: command-line, batch, batch-file

Sorry, the title isn't very descriptive, but I couldn't think of a better one.

I use this script to drag and drop video + audio file, and combine them with ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -i "%~2" -c copy "C:\New Folder\%~n1".mp4
```

It works great, but the input, and subsequently output files have ".raw" ending before the extension. Is there an easy way remove the last 4 characters of %~n1 or replace ".raw" with ""? I want to manipulate the string before assigning it as file name with ffmpeg, I don't want to output the file with .raw.mp4 ending, and then rename it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the answer that works

```
set filename=%~n1
set filename=%filename:.raw=%
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -i "%~2" -c copy "%filename%.mp4"
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there an easy way remove the last 4 characters of `%~n1`?

You need to use the substring operator. Try the following `cmd` script:

```
@echo off
rem avoid polluting global environment space
setlocal
set "_file=%~n1"
rem strip last 4 characters from _file
set "_name=%_file~0,-4%"
rem run ffmpeg with new name
ffmpeg -i "%~1" -i "%~2" -c copy "C:\New Folder\%_name%".mp4
endlocal
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line | SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/)
- [Windows CMD Commands (categorized) - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [Endlocal - Local environment variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/endlocal.html)
- [Setlocal - Local variables - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/setlocal.html)
- [variable substring - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html)

Comment: I get an error

`C:\New Folder".mp4: Invalid argument`

Comment: Try moving the `"` after the `4`

Comment: That just outputs `.mp4` file without a name. Feels like `%_name%` isn't passing anything.

Comment: I assume you meant the last " in `ffmpeg -i "%~1" -i "%~2" -c copy "C:\New Folder\%_name%".mp4`

Comment: Yes, `"C:\New Folder\%_name%.mp4"`

Comment: Yeah, that just outputs `.mp4` file without a name.

Comment: missing the `~` in `set "_file=%n1"`. Change to: `set "_file=%~n1"`

Comment: @DD3R See revised answer

Comment: @T3RR0R @DavidPostill It's still the same result. Either `C:\New Folder".mp4: Invalid argument` or `.mp4` file without a name, depending on the " placement in ffmpeg output path. the ~ didn't change the result.